# Need help understanding a statement about energy in capacitors

Tags: potential, work, potential-energy, capacitance

The  electric  potential  energy  stored  in  a  charged  capacitor  is  just  equal  to  the  amount  of  work  required  to  charge  it—that  is,  to  separate  opposite  charges and place them on different conductors. When the capacitor is discharged, this stored energy is recovered as work done by electrical forces.

So is the work done by a battery? And if so every time it moves a certain charge over to another conductor, does it gradually get harder to keep moving the charges since the charges that are being moved do negative work on those coming in after them?

I know that work is how much force is applied for a certain distance. How should i think about work in this situation?

And finally can someone expand on that final sentence. As i understand it, once the capacitor is disccharged, the charges do work on one another to bring it to a state of no "net charge". Is this correct?